# Batch Text editor not editing correctly

Tags: batch-file, text, editor

Right now I have this

```
@ECHO off
COLOR 1f
SET /p name=What is the name of the file you want to open/name: 
CLS
SET /p type=What type of file do you want to open/make (txt, vbs, etc.): 
CLS
IF EXIST %name%.%type% ( TYPE %name%.%type% )
:begin
SET /p code=
ECHO %code% >> %name%.%type%
GOTO begin
CLS
```

But once it displays the text that is already in the file with the TYPE command, i cant edit that part that it displays, i can only add more.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are trying to use batch commands to create a text editor?  You might be better off learning a real programming language.

Comment: I know other languages, I was just trying to challenge myself and see if I could do this.

Comment: You need the batch file to find the line of text put it in a variable and be able to edit it. :/

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to do: _Replace_ the first N lines with the new N ones? _Insert_ the new lines before the existing ones?

Comment: I am trying to display the text of a file and then be able to edit that and save it to the file but when it displays the text that is already in the file, it wont let me erase that to change it to something else. If you try the code out for yourself you might understand what i mean

Comment: Your code only adds to a text file.  What is your question?

Comment: cmd is line-based, not screen-based. So you have to edit line by line (more like good old `edlin` instead of `edit`). Instead of just `type` the file, do a `findstr /n`, ask for linenumber to edit, edit (or re-type) the line and write the whole file with the changed line. Possible but challenging. Working with that might be a bit confusing with bigger files.